# javscript recursion string reverse

Tags: javascript, string, recursion

I tried to find a recursive solution on my own to reverse a string s but it returns 'undefined' for strings >1 char.
Can somebody please help me to debug this?
I know it is not the elegant way but finding the error could help me advancing.

Thank U very  much!

```
var revFunc = function (s, r, n, i) {
  if (i > n) {
    return r;
  }

  r = r + s[n - i];
  i++;
  revFunc(s, r, n, i);
};

var reverse = function (s) {
  var r = "";
  var n = s.length - 1;
  var i = 0;
  if (n < 1) {
    return s;
  }
  return revFunc(s, r, n, i);
};
```

Comment: First of all, attend to your indentation. It'll make your code much more managable and easier to read - for you and us.

Comment: you need a return stament before you call the function again. `return revFunc(s, r, n, i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not a good fit for recursion

While the minor correction already presented fixes your function, I want to suggest that this version shows a misunderstanding about recursion.

Your function is using recursion to update what would otherwise be local variables in a while loop.  It could be rewritten like this:

```js
var reverse = function (s) {
  var r = "";
  var n = s.length - 1;
  var i = 0;
  if (n < 1) {
    return s;
  }
  while (i <= n) {
    r = r + s[n - i]
    i++
  }
  return r
};

console .log (reverse ('abcde'))
```

The recursion you use is just another means of writing that same code.

Recursion is meant for something a bit different.  We want our algorithms to match our data structures.  For recursion to really be meaningful, we should should use it on a recursive data structure.

But we *can* do so for this problem.

### Thinking of a string recursively

There are often many different ways to think of a single data structure.  We can think of a string as a recursive structure this way:

> A string is either
>
> - The empty string, "", or
> - a character followed by a string

We can call the two parts of a non-empty string the `head` and the `tail`.

### Using the recursive definition in a recursive algorithm

With that formulation, we can write a recursive algorithm that matches the structure:

> The reversal of a string is either
>
> - The reversal of the empty string (which is still the empty string), or
> - The reversal of tail, followed by the head

Then the code practically writes itself:

```js
const reverse = (string) =>
  string .length == 0
    ? ""
    : reverse (string .slice (1)) + string[0]
    
console .log (reverse ('abcdefg'))
```

### Variants

There are certainly variations of this possible.  We could want to be ready for when tail-call-optimization is finally common in JS environments, and could change this to a tail-recursive version, something like

```js
const reverse = (string, result = "") =>
  string .length == 0
    ? result
    : reverse (string .slice (1), string [0] + result)
```

(Note that there is a potential problem with this style.  Default parameters can get in the way of using the function in certain contexts.  You cannot, for instance, successfully call `strings .map (reverse)` with this version.  You could do this by splitting it into a helper function and a main function, but that's taking us afield.)

Or, taking advantage of the fact that strings are iterables, we could write a nicely simple version using parameter destructuring along with a default value:

```js
const reverse = ([head = undefined, ...tail]) =>
  head == undefined
    ? ""
    : reverse (tail) + head
```

### The advantages of recursion

And it's hard to imagine getting much simpler than that.  This version captures the algorithm quite directly.  And the algorithm is cleanly tied to our description of the data structure.

Note one thing that none of these functions use: *local variables*.  Simple recursion can often be written in such a way that there is no need for them.  This is a major blessing, because that means there is no place for mutable state to hide.  And mutable state is the source of many, many programming errors.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `return`

`return revFunc(s, r, n, i);`

Updated:

```
var revFunc = function (s, r, n, i) {
  if (i > n) {
    return r;
  }
  r = r + s[n - i];
  i++;
  return revFunc(s, r, n, i);
};
```

**Suggestion:** Please use better name for variables, it sucks `s,r,n,i`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try a simple solution :

```
let str = "hello";
let reverse_str = str.split("").reverse().join("");
```

Comment: "I tried to find a recursive solution on my own to reverse a string."   This looks much more like a learning exercise than an attempt to find the best reversal technique around.